# Is it acceptable to express this sentence without using the "dass" or "als ob" clause?

Tags: subordinate-clause

> Sie können es nicht, ohne das Gefühl zu haben, **ihnen würden die Flügel gestutzt**.

Or does the expression "das Gefühl haben" always need to be followed by the "dass" or "als ob" clause?

> Sie können es nicht, ohne das Gefühl zu haben, **dass die Flügel ihnen gestutzt würden**.
>
> Sie können es nicht, ohne das Gefühl zu haben, **als ob die Flügel ihnen gestutzt würden**.

Comment: The first sentence is the most eloquent one, to be true. The second and the third are acceptable, but it's more common to place *ihnen* directly behind *dass* resp. *als ob*.

Comment: Mir gefällt „das Gefühl, als ob“ nicht. Vielleicht „ein Gefühl, als ob“.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's acceptable to express the sentence without using *dass*. This is called [Uneingeleiteter Nebensatz](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Objekt/uneingeleitet.html) and can in general be used with verbs that express reported speech, thoughts, opinions, impressions, wishes etc.